# What are induced probability distributions over group orbits called?

Tags: probability, abstract-algebra, group-theory, measure-theory, permutations

Let $G$ be a group acting a on some space $\mathcal{X}$ via a group action $\circ : G \times \mathcal{X} \rightarrow \mathcal{X}$.
The orbit of an element $x \in \mathcal{X}$ is defined as $[x] = \{g \circ x \mid g \in G \}$.
Let $\mathcal{X} \mathbin{/} G$ be the set of all orbits, i.e. $\mathcal{X} \mathbin{/} G = \{[x] \mid x \in \mathcal{X}\}$.

If we have a random variable $x \in \mathcal{X}$ with $x \sim D$ for some distribution D, then $[x]$ is also a random variable with support on $\mathcal{X} \mathbin{/} G$ and we have $[x] \sim D'$ for some distribution $D'$.

Right now, I am struggling to find literature on such induced distributions. Therefore, I am wondering:

1.) What one would call the distribution / measure associated with $[z]$?
2.) What subfield of mathematics studies such distributions / measures? (I've come across ergodic theory, but that appears to only be dealing with group actions fulfilling specific constraints.)

---

Here's a bit of additional motivation:
I want to define a distribution $D$ over graph adjacency matrices $\{0,1\}^{N \times N}$ such that the distribution of the orbits induced by the symmetric / permutation group is "nice" / easy to evaluate.
Alternatively, I want to determine the distribution of orbits for a given distribution $D$ over adjacency matrices.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pushforward_measure

Comment: You're obviously right. This is a specific type of pushforward measure.
I was just wondering if there is a group-theory-specific term for this special kind of pushforward measure :)